# Import data to Analytics in Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-tour#combine-with-imported-data) you can import a data file to Analytics in Application Insights by clicking Settings. I have no such button at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is a preview feature right now and you need to opt in. There is a contact us link inside of Application Analytics under "Other Data Sources"

Comment: Thanks. Alright, I submitted my e-mail and I'm waiting for the response.

Comment: No response though. Can I expect anything soon?

Comment: Not sure of the turn around time on that team. I'll ping the group and see what the criteria is.

Comment: it is now public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start by signing up to this feature. Look at the bottom of the schema pane at the left, under "Other Data Sources." See comments at the end of this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics-tour